# How does the expression `ap zip tail` work

Tags: haskell, types, pointfree

I wondered how to write `f x = zip x (tail x)` in point free. So I used the pointfree program and the result was `f = ap zip tail`. `ap` being a function from Control.Monad

I do not understand how the point free definition works. I hope I can figure it out if I can comprehend it from the perspective of types.

```
import Control.Monad (ap)
let f = ap zip tail
let g = ap zip
:info ap zip tail f g
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
    -- Defined in `Control.Monad'
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]   -- Defined in `GHC.List'
tail :: [a] -> [a]      -- Defined in `GHC.List'
f :: [b] -> [(b, b)]    -- Defined at <interactive>:3:5
g :: ([a] -> [b]) -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
    -- Defined at <interactive>:4:5
```

By looking at the expression `ap zip tail` I would think that zip is the first parameter of `ap` and tail is the second parameter of `ap`.

```
Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
           \--------/   \---/
              zip        tail
```

But this is not possible, because the types of `zip` and `tail` are completely different than what the function `ap` requires. Even with taking into consideration that the list is a monad of sorts.

Comment: The only think I can come up with is that the `a` in the ap type becomes the `[a] -> [b]` of the type of zip. If it is the case, then what the unification (if it is the proper word) rules that govern this are in general?

Comment: ghci says the type is `ap zip tail :: Monad ((->) [b]) => [b] -> [(b, b)]`... without too much investigation, I'd say the `Monad ((->) [b])` is what you want to read up on.  I *think* http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#reader might help you understand what's going on here.

Comment: Incidentally, `zip <*> tail` is equivalent and prettier looking

Comment: @jozefg To me the prettiest of them all is the original `f x = zip x (tail x)` Probably because it is the only form that allows me to see the authors intent right away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the type signature of `ap` is `Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`.  You've given it `zip` and `tail` as arguments, so let's look at their type signatures.

Starting with `tail :: [a] -> [a] ~ (->) [a] [a]` (here `~` is the equality operator for types), if we compare this type against the type of the second argument for `ap`,

```
 (->) [x]  [x] ~ m a
((->) [x]) [x] ~ m a
```

we get `a ~ [x]` and `m ~ ((->) [x]) ~ ((->) a)`.  Already we can see that the monad we're in is `(->) [x]`, not `[]`.  If we substitute what we can into the type signature of `ap` we get:

```
(((->) [x]) ([x] -> b)) -> (((->) [x]) [x]) -> (((->) [x]) b)
```

Since this is not very readable, it can more normally be written as

```
  ([x] -> ([x] -> b)) -> ([x] -> [x]) -> ([x] -> b)
~ ([x] ->  [x] -> b ) -> ([x] -> [x]) -> ([x] -> b)
```

The type of `zip` is `[x] -> [y] -> [(x, y)]`.  We can already see that this lines up with the first argument to `ap` where

```
[x]         ~    [x]   
[y]         ~    [x]   
[(x, y)]    ~    b
```

Here I've listed the types vertically so that you can easily see which types line up.  So obviously `x ~ x`, `y ~ x`, and `[(x, y)] ~ [(x, x)] ~ b`, so we can finish substituting `b ~ [(x, x)]` into `ap`'s type signature and get

```
([x] -> [x] -> [(x, x)]) -> ([x] -> [x]) -> ([x] -> [(x, x)])
--   zip                        tail        ( ap  zip  tail )
--                                            ap  zip  tail u = zip u (tail u)
```

I hope that clears things up for you.

**EDIT**: As [danvari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78264/danvari) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181917/how-does-the-expression-ap-zip-tail-work#comment28382173_19182589) in the comments, the monad `(->) a` is sometimes called the reader monad.

Comment: might be worth to mention that (->) is the Reader-monad

Answer (score 6):

There are two aspects to understanding this:

1. The type magic
2. The information flow of the implementation

Firstly, this helped me understand the **type magic**:

```
1) zip          : [a] → ( [a] → [(a,a)] )
2) tail         : [a] → [a]
3) zip <*> tail : [a] → [(a,a)]

4) <*> : Applicative f ⇒ f (p → q) → f p → f q
```

In this case, for `<*>`,

```
5) f x = y → x
```

Note that in 5, `f` is a type constructor.  Applying `f` to `x`  produces a type. Also, here `=` is overloaded to mean equivalence of types.

`y` is currently a place-holder, in this case, it is `[a]`, which means

```
6) f x = [a] -> x
```

Using 6, we can rewrite 1,2 and 3 as follows:

```
7) zip          : f ([a] → [(a,a)])
8) tail         : f [a]
9) zip <*> tail : f ([a] → [(a,a)])  →  f [a]  →  f [(a,a)]
```

So, looking at 4, we are substituting as follows:

```
10) p = [a]
11) q = [(a,a)]
12) f x =  [a] → x
```

(Repetition of 6 here again as 12 )

Secondly, the **information flow**, i.e. the actual functionality.  This is easier, it is clear from the definition of `<*>` for the [Applicative instance of `y →`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-617), which is rewritten here with different identifier names and using infix style:

```
13) g <*> h $ xs = g xs (h xs)
```

Substituting as follows:

```
14) g = zip
15) h = tail
```

Gives:

```
zip <*> tail $ xs        (Using 14 and 15)
  ==
zip xs (tail xs)         (Using 13 )
```

Comment: The part that is still unclear to me is how you get step 5 (which seems to be ghc automatically inferring that we want to use (->)). Can it do this automatically because it's the only applicative instance that works?