# How does one read Haskell's `ap zip tail` to mean `\x -> zip x (tail x)`?

Tags: haskell

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181917/how-does-the-expression-ap-zip-tail-work) discussed how the type of Haskell expression `ap zip tail` can be translated into the type of `\x -> zip x (tail x)`. It was enlightening, but neither the question nor answer there dealt with *why* the former expression gives the same results as the latter expression, only that their types are equivalent. For all I know it could've meant `\x -> zip x (tail (tail x))` instead.

I tried reading the documentation for [ap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) but got nowhere. How does one *read* `ap` to get the understanding that `ap zip tail` gives the same results as `\x -> zip x (tail x)` ?

Comment: in case you wonder how you can find out yourself: first seach it: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ap you see that you most likely use the monad instance so look at `Monad`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad and see if you can find the right instance below (it is `Monad ((->) r)` here) - there is hopefully a link to the source (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-621) and voila (also look at the source for `ap`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#ap)

Answer (score 7):

First, look at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#ap) as well:

```
ap m1 m2          = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (x1 x2) }
-- Since many Applicative instances define (<*>) = ap, we
-- cannot define ap = (<*>)
```

You know (from the previous question) that the monad we are interested in is `(->) [a]`. Since we know from that comment that `ap` is the same as `(<*>)`, next we look at

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

`(<*>) zip tail x = zip x (tail x)` and we can move `x` to the right and get `zip <*> tail = \x -> zip x (tail x)`.

You could also use the definition of `ap` and `instance Monad (->) a` directly without looking at `<*>`, but this would take a bit more effort.

> For all I know it could've meant \x -> zip x (tail (tail x)) instead.

*This* is actually impossible just from the type: `m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b` is `(c -> (a -> b)) -> (c -> a) -> (c -> b)` in this monad, so `ap f1 f2` can't apply `f2` twice: it has type `c -> a` and `f2 (f2 <anything>)` wouldn't typecheck.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32598709/4161344) explains it.  Remember that `<*>` is the same as `ap`, but just as an infix operator, and as part of `Applicative` rather than it's subclass, `Monad`, since only `Applicative` is needed for it to work.